# Displaying the selected string from Android Spinner

Tags: java, android

```
    String chooseTime[] = {"7.00 - 9.00", "9.00 - 11.00", "11.00 - 13.00", "13.00 - 15.00", "15.00 - 17.00", "17.00 - 18.30" };
    spTimeConsegna = (Spinner)     
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.timeChooseConsegna);
    adapterChooseTimeConsegna = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, chooseTime);
    adapterChooseTimeConsegna.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spTimeConsegna.setAdapter(adapterChooseTimeConsegna);

    chooseTimeConsegna = chooseTime[spTimeConsegna.getSelectedItemPosition()];
```

I want to save the selected value of the spinner in the chooseTimeConsegna String, but it always saves the first value of the chooseTime string array indifferently what is choosen in the spinner. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing this in `onCreate` method, so it's only called when that activity is started, not every time you select things on spinner. Try something like this:

```java
yourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        String chooseTime[] = {"7.00 - 9.00", "9.00 - 11.00", "11.00 - 13.00", "13.00 - 15.00", "15.00 - 17.00", "17.00 - 18.30" };
        chooseTimeConsegna = chooseTime[position];
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    }
});
```

This method is gonna be called every time you select something on your spinner, and argument `position` is the position of the selected item in the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
chooseTimeConsegna = chooseTime[spTimeConsegna.getSelectedItemPosition()];
```

With:

```
spTimeConsegna.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        chooseTimeConsegna = chooseTime[position];
    }
});
```

You should be good to go.